# Select shows object for selected value with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have a select component that loads the values fine, but no matter what I put as the value it always comes back as object.  I've tried the following

```
<select [(ngModel)]="p.selectedUser">
    <option *ngFor="let u of p.practiceUsers;let i of index;" [value]="i">{{ u.userName }}</option>
</select>

<select [(ngModel)]="p.selectedUser">
    <option *ngFor="let u of p.practiceUsers;let i of index;" [value]="u">{{ u.userName }}</option>
</select>

<select [(ngModel)]="p.selectedUser">
    <option *ngFor="let u of p.practiceUsers;let i of index;" value="{{i}}">{{ u.userName }}</option>
</select>
```

If on the page below the select I put `{{ p.selectedUser | json}}` it shows `[object object]`

I have selects like this all over my app, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  The value of p.selectedUser by default comes from the server and is just an empty string.

The practiceUser object is something like this: `{ userId: 1, userName: "Joe Smith" }`

For further reference here are screenshots.
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're doing `*ngFor="let u of p.practiceUsers` and the `practiceUser` object is `{ userId: 1, userName: "Joe Smith" }`.... your are doing an `*ngFor` in an object?

Comment: Have you tried to log `{{ p.selectedUser.value | json }}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I never got it to recognize the value of u, but I did get it to use the index as the value by changing this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="p.selectedUser">
    <option *ngFor="let u of p.practiceUsers;let i = index;" [value]="i">{{ u.userName }}</option>
</select>
```

I had a of instead of a =

Answer (score 1):

Second approach should be good. Are you sure you have the right data in p?

Comment: It makes sense if  `[value]="u"` and `u` is the user object, and its property `u.userName` is the label.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Comment: @Jimenemex only because IMHO the post does not really attempt to answer the question. By the way, which one is the second approach?